# Unable install dotless nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, nuget

I am trying to get an asp.net mvc project working with LessCSS. The few tutorials I have found say you need to install the dotless nuget package however I cant seem to get it right: See below:

```
PM> Install-Package dotLess
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'dotLess'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package dotLess
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Is this package outdate or depricated?

What package should I be using now to let mvc bundle compile Less Scripts?

Comment: Use `Install-Package dotless -Version 1.4.4`

Comment: Is the package supported and maintained? I don't want to start a new project with a dependency on an unreliable library?

Comment: Its very much reliable and stable https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotless/

Comment: @Satpal same error: `The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\Dylan.AMECOR\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find version '1.4.4' of package 'dotless'.`